# Jax rs genric exception

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have implemented the below generic exception. I am getting the below exception on running it.

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Could not find exception type for
>   given ExceptionMapper class: class Exception_Mapper.GenericMapper.

```
@Provider
public class GenericMapper<E extends Throwable> 
                  implements ExceptionMapper<E> {

    @Override
    public  Response toResponse(E ex ) {

        //Exception E1 = E;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Response.status(Response.Status.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
                       .entity(ex).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public class GenericMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>`?

Comment: I tink both should work same way. If not could you please help me understand why??...

Comment: When you have the generic `GenericMapper<E extends Throwable>`, where do you think the container will get the concrete argument for `E` from?

Comment: AFAIK it will come from the exception class occured. For example throw EmployeeNotFoundException should call generic mapper with E as the class EmployeeNotFoundException.

Comment: No. An exception mapper declares what exception it maps by specifying the type argument to the implemented ExceptionMapper. If you want a "catch-all" mapper, then you should have `GenericMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>` (I don't think `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` is a good idea, but I haven't read about it)

Comment: It makes no sense what you are trying to. You just use the highest exception in the hierarchy to catch all. That's how the mappers work. It will search all the way up the exception superclass hierarchy until it finds a mapper that matches the exception. Everything falls under Throwable so it will catch all. Unless there are other mappers, for more specific exceptions, then those will be used for those exceptions and all subclasses of that exception.